# Most efficient way to determine how class use to Deserialize XML

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xsd

I have many .xsd files for many xml schemas

example

**XML 1.0 - xml_1_0.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <cars version="1.00">
         <car>Honda</car>
         <car>Ferrari</car>
     </cars>
```

**XML 2.0 - xml_2_0.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <cars version="2.00">
     <car>
       <name>Honda</name>
       <color>White</color>
     </car>

     <car>
       <name>Honda</name>
       <color>Red</color>
     </car>
 </cars>
```

I create my classes from .xsd like this

```
xsd.exe cars_1_0.xsd /c

xsd.exe cars_2_0.xsd /c
```

And Deserialize like this:

```
foreach(string file in files) {
     XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
     doc.Load(file);    
     string version =   doc.SelectSingleNode("/Cars/@version").Value;

     if(version == "1.00")
     {
         Stream reader = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open);
         XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(v1.Cars));

         v1.Cars XML = new v1.Cars();
         XML = (v1.Cars)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
     } 
     else if(version == "2.00") 
     {
         Stream reader = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open);
         XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(v2.Cars));

         v2.Cars XML = new v2.Cars();
         XML = (v2.Cars)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
     }
}
```

Does anyone know a better way to do this, or have a better performance?

Comment: Can you share the actual XSD?  Is modifying the XSD an option?  Is creating a new class an option?

Comment: in the quetion i wrote just an example, the xsd files are much more complex, and any version of xml has many other attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options, depending on how far you want to take this.  One fairly non invasive option would be to not use `XmlDocument` and avoid loading the stream more than once.  For example, your existing code could be simplified/streamlined to :

```
foreach (string file in files)
{
    using (var stream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open))
    {
        var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.CloseInput = false;
        string version = "";
        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
        {
            if (xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("Cars"))
            {
                version = xmlReader.GetAttribute("version");
            }
            else
            {
                throw new XmlException("Could not get 'version' attribute of 'Cars' root element!");
            }                    
        }
        stream.Position = 0;
        if (version == "1.00")
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(v1.Cars));

            v1.Cars XML = new v1.Cars();
            XML = (v1.Cars)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
        }
        else if (version == "2.00")
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(v2.Cars));

            v2.Cars XML = new v2.Cars();
            XML = (v2.Cars)serializer.Deserialize(stream);

        }
    }
}
```

Since you're just reading off the root element, you might even be able to get away with deserializing from the `XmlReader` and not have to reset the position on the `FileStream`.

This avoids the overhead of loading the entire file twice (once for `XmlDocument`, then again for `XmlSerializer`) - and particularly avoids the memory overhead of creating a DOM for each document.

A more nuclear option would be implementing `IXmlSerializable` on a set of custom classes, which would have custom logic in the `ReadXml` methods to parse the version attribute and instantiate the correct child type(s) - e.g. a `CarCollection` class that has a `List<Car>` property, where `Car` is an abstract class that has `CarV1` and `CarV2` as descendants.  This would be about as efficient as you could get (and offer very fine grained control over your class hierarchy design), but would eliminate the possibility of using xsd.exe to generate your classes.